# How to display all categories for an industry which has sub_categories into grouped_collection_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models. Industry, ProductCategory and ProductSubCategory. And the association between them is like following:

```
class Industry
  has_many :product_categories
end

class ProductCategory
  belongs_to :industry, optional: true
  has_many :product_sub_categories
end

class ProductSubCategory
  belongs_to :product_category
end
```

And I am displaying select on using:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :product_category %>
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :product_category_id, Industry.all, 
    :product_categories, :name, :id, :name, { selected: 
     @product.product_category_id }, { class: "form-control form-
     control-alt", required: true } %>
 </div>
```

But this is not working as I want. It is displaying all product categories under each industry but I just want to display only product categories which has sub categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has two parts in it:

#### 1. Selecting categories which have subcategories.

If you have a lot of data - better option is using [counter cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) - add `product_sub_categories_count` column to categories, set `counter_cache:true` on belongs_to and call `ProductCategory.reset_counters(id, :product_sub_categories)` for each category id after migration to fill.

And then:

```
scope :with_subcategories, ->{ where('product_sub_categories_count > 0') }
```

Other simple solution for small datasets is to calculate this in runtime:

```
scope :with_subcategories, ->{
  joins(:product_sub_categories).group(:id).select("product_categories.*, count(*) as product_sub_categories_count").
  having('product_sub_categories_count > 0')
}
```

#### 2. Using this in grouped_collection_select

Once we have scope - this becomes easier:

```
class Industry
  ...
  has_many :product_categories_with_subcategories, ->{ with_subcategories }
end

f.grouped_collection_select :product_category_id, Industry.all, 
  :product_categories_with_subcategories, :name, :id, :name,
```